# Webpack is not generating map files for js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm having a problem with webpack in the case that it's not generating any map files, even if I set the source map file name option or changed the devtool option. The only map file generated is the css one from extract text plugin.

My configuration is the following:

```
const config = {
  entry: {
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    index: path.join(rootDirPath, 'src', 'www', 'client')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(rootDirPath, 'public'),
    filename: 'scripts/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: `/`
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: [
            'es2015',
            'react'
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles/[name].[contenthash].css'),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(rootDirPath, 'src', 'www', 'views', 'index.tmpl.html'),
      filename: 'index.html',
    })
  ],
  resolveLoader: {
    modulesDirectories: [
      path.join(rootDirPath, 'node_modules')
    ]
  },
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help.